# TYPO3 crdate field in MM table

Tags: typo3

I have typo3 7.6.18

```
 #
 # Table structure for table 'tx_feusersplus_user_service_mm'
 #
 CREATE TABLE tx_feusersplus_user_service_mm (
    uid_local int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    uid_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    KEY uid_local (uid_local),
    KEY uid_foreign (uid_foreign)
 );
```

This is table for MM relation. I want to add crdate field to this table and use it. Field for I can know, when item was added (time). Is it possible ?

I can add this field, but how I can use it ? How to get it in model and in fluid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MM tables cannot have any attributes besides the relations to records.

You can however, promote this table to a regular one by adding TCA and using it as regular foreign table instead of MM. The name could then change to `tx_feusersplus_user_service`. This way your relation table can have all regular table fields.

If you are using an Extbase `ObjectStorage` here you'll need to change its item type to your new `UserService` model. That model has one property `user` and one property `service`, each with the desired domain model.

One example of such a rich relation table in TYPO3 is `sys_file_reference` which is basically only a link between records and files but is used explicitly.

Comment: If I understood you right I just should define this table tx_feusersplus_user_service_mm   in TCA ? I also want use object storage, so I must save mm in the name ?

Comment: Yes, you need TCA for that table which turns it from a MM to a full table. And no, you don't need the `_mm` anymore. I'll extend my answer for Extbase.