# Extbase: Additional fields in MM table

Tags: typo3, extbase

I try to find a possibility to store some extra fields in the MM table (and take it into account in queries). I have a user table (extended fe_users) and an events table. The user can sign in for an event. I want to store the information if the user actually has visited the event and furthermore a flag indicating wheter the visit has been exportet.

In my ext_tables.sql I've already added the two fields and they're present in the database. But I'v got no idea how to filter the events based on the new fields in my repository.

Any sugestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TYPO3 crdate field in MM table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707144/typo3-crdate-field-in-mm-table)

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks! Unfortunately this does'n work without writing a complex backend module, because the editors should be able to assign an event directly to the user (currently with a side-by-side select). I now use a raw sql statement inside of the repository, this is surely not perfect but works for now.

Comment: You can continue to use the table as MM in the BE without change. You only need to add TCA for that table and adjust your Extbase domain models to use it explicitly.

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks again! It took a while until I really understood the workflow, but now it works ;-)

Comment: Great. :-) If you like, you can vote for my linked answer and close your question.